# How to properly implement a structured menu in php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

my goal is to tweak/replace the existing wordpress `php` menu code, having as a start point, this `html`/`css`/`js` menu structure in codepen:

[*Home / Portfolio / About*](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dowoKr) and going down in *Portfolio* structure, another page having [*Home / Portfolio projects*](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpZpQp).

In a few words, I've registered in `script-calls.php` the `mynewmenu.js` file with the following sequence

`js`:

```
// mynewmenu implementation
jQuery(function($){ 
    var height, index, prevIndex

    $('nav ul li').mouseover(function(e){
        //Set the aesthetics (similar to :hover)
        $('nav ul li').removeClass('hovered');
        $(this).addClass('hovered');

        //Gets relevant data required for scrolling of menuRight    
        height = $("#menuRight").css("height").replace('px','');
        index = $(this).index();

        //If the category button (from the navlist) has changed
        if (index != prevIndex){
            $("#menuRight").stop();

            $("#menuRight").animate({"scrollTop":height*index}, 800, 'easeOutBounce'); //This requires jQuery UI for easing options.
            prevIndex = index;
        }
    });
});
```

I've created the desired menu structure (assigning different menus to different pages as u'll see [here](http://goo.gl/xGBMtI)) and I've identified the `php` that manage the existing menu structure:

```
            <!-- Start Header -->
                 ...                
                <div class="myrow max_width ">      
                    <div class="small-5 <?php if ($header_style == 'style2') { echo 'medium-8'; } else { echo 'medium-4';} ?> columns menu-holder">
                        <?php $full_menu_true = ($menu_mobile_toggle_view == 'style2' && $header_style == 'style2');?>
                        <?php if ($full_menu_true) { ?>
                            <nav id="full-menu" role="navigation">
                                <?php if ($page_menu) { ?>
                                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => $page_menu, 'depth' => 2, 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'full-menu', 'walker' => new thb_mobileDropdown  ) ); ?>
                                <?php } else  if(has_nav_menu('nav-menu')) { ?>
                                  <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'nav-menu', 'depth' => 2, 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'full-menu', 'walker' => new thb_mobileDropdown ) ); ?>
                                <?php } else { ?>
                                    <ul class="full-menu">
                                        <li><a href="<?php echo get_admin_url().'nav-menus.php'; ?>">Please assign a menu from Appearance -> Menus</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                <?php } ?>

              /* I think that <div id='menuRight'> html sequences *translated*
              in *php* should begin here in a conditional manner: *if* we find ourself on the
              Home page, should be activated Home / Portfolio / About sequence and also if we
              are on the Portfolio page, we should receive the menu 2, generated by Home / Portfolio 
              projects sequence. More details below. */  

                            </nav>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php if ($header_search != 'off') { do_action( 'thb_quick_search' ); } ?>
                        <?php if ($header_cart != 'off') { do_action( 'thb_quick_cart' ); } ?>
                        <a href="#" data-target="open-menu" class="mobile-toggle<?php if (!$full_menu_true) { ?> always<?php } ?>">
                            <div>
                                <span></span><span></span><span></span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>          
                </div>  

            </header>
            <!-- End Header -->
```

At this point, my question is, how can I implement into the `header.php` the following `html` sequences that generate the rollover images linked to the menu buttons, keeping in mind that there are different  sections, each menu with his section as follow. Home / Portfolio / About:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
   ...
  </ul>
    <div id='menuRight'>
       <div>
           Home
           <img src='http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/31100000/random-space-space-31155586-598-398.jpg'>
          </img>
       </div>
      <div>
          Portfolio
          <img src='http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg'>
          </img>
      </div>
      <div>
          About
          <img src='http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/31100000/random-space-space-31155586-598-398.jpg'>
          </img>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

and menu 2, Home / Portfolio projects:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    ...
  </ul>
    <div id='menuRight'>
       <div>
           Home
           <img src='http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/31100000/random-space-space-31155586-598-398.jpg'>
          </img>
       </div>
      <div>
          Fiva
          <img src='http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg'>
          </img>
      </div>
      <div>
          Caterham
          <img src='http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/31100000/random-space-space-31155586-598-398.jpg'>
          </img>
      </div>
      <div>
          Mobile
          <img src='http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg'>
          </img>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I left intentionally the `css` out of discussion because, that's another chapter of this code tweak.

LE: I have to mention that the rollover image effect activated by the menu buttons, will be enough (and make sense) for it to be available, only on the [Home page](http://goo.gl/xGBMtI) and [Portfolio page](http://goo.gl/iWDM9c) of the site. I think that It could be very tricky to achieve the same effect when we have a project page opened (let's say [FIVA](http://goo.gl/gTsV5F)) and have the mouse over another project button for example.

LE2: regarding the rollover images, I am not looking for a fancy `php` code that's supposed to grab a preview of the last project or something; a `php` code that allows me to predefine image source links like we have in the above `html` menu sections, will be just fine, taking in consideration the fact that these images will not be replaced so often.

LE3: Pure experimental, and please correct me, I was just thinking, using [include PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) to call two separate `html` files in `header.php` (including in these the above described menu 1 and 2 sections) could be the beginning of a workaround?

```
                <!-- Start Header -->
                     ...                
                    <div class="myrow max_width ">      
                        ...
                                        <ul class="full-menu">
                                            <li><a href="<?php echo get_admin_url().'nav-menus.php'; ?>">Please assign a menu from Appearance -> Menus</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                       <?php
                  /* But there still should be a php code, that call the  
                  html sections *if* we are on Homepage or Portfolio page.  
                  Something like:
                  Php instructions, if Home page */  

             include('menu1section.html');

                  // and also php instructions, if Portfolio page 

             include('menu2section.html');
                                        ?>

                                </nav>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php if ($header_search != 'off') { do_action( 'thb_quick_search' ); } ?>
                            ...
                    </div>  

                </header>
                <!-- End Header -->
```

Any thoughts? Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a wordpress dev, but it seems to me you need a way to detect the active category/post/page? you are on... it's difficult to understand your data structures from looking at the website.

```
<!-- Start Header -->
...                
<div class="myrow max_width ">      
...
    <ul class="full-menu">
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_admin_url().'nav-menus.php'; ?>">
            Please assign a menu from Appearance -> Menus
        </a></li>
    </ul>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php
        $thisCat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'));
        switch ($thisCat->name) {
            case 'Home':
                echo "Home test";
                break;
            case 'Portfolio':
                echo "portfolio test";
                break;
            case 'About Us':
                echo "About Us test";
                break;
        }
    ?>
....
<!-- End Header -->
```

Revised my answer to give you a better idea of what test I'm referring too.

Comment: Hi there. Unfortunately (for me) It's pretty difficult to re-write the menu code and after that to integrate the `html` to `php` conversion if that is your technical proposal. Actually that's why I've opened the thread and it's all I need.. to integrate somehow the above mentioned `html` sections, using a conditional `php` function in the existing menu, into the `header.php` file. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I understand, can you indicate if my code above at least enables you to detect the active section the user is viewing? A quick test would be to modify my includes to echo a unique number for each case statement... then see if the representative number is visible on each url. I think your only solution here is to first crack the page detection issue and then once that is accomplished - the menu structure problem.

Comment: I would love to try it but can you please specify where exactly should I put that code? More than that, I don't have any home.php, portfolio.php, about-us.php pages. I think that there is a misunderstanding, in Wordpress, everything is generated dynamically.

Comment: Just inside your header file, in replacements to your include lines. Ha, my code is more pseudo code to show how multiple UI could be achieved. You'd have to create the PHP files and place your <html /> and/or <?php ?> in them...

Comment: The above code is a potential solution to the detect page question. Once you have a method of detecting the page you are on, you can build code to solve the custom navigation question... One step at a time! Goodluck

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to implement your solution but not so sure if I understand what's the deal with creating stand alone pages, as long as wordpress will already generate them (?!) I'm confused :)

Comment: I've updated the `header.php`.Can you please have a [look](http://neuegrid.com), that's all? I am asking because I can't see yet the point of your first step in solving the main problem (not your fault, it's my lack of php knowledge).

Comment: I can't see my test code output, are you sure you've placed it in your site? I think this would be easier if you e-mail me for further support as these comments could go on a while... My contact details are on my website, the URL for which you can find on my stack profile. Otherwise, best of luck!

Comment: Sure, thanks. As I've said in earlyer e-mail, I've updated the `header.php` maybe I miss an intermediate step, not so sure if I understood correctly the whole process. Anyway, if will be possible, my e-mail invitation to discuss in [chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86976/discussion-between-typo-78-and-dan-belden) remain available. I do need your support and I appreciate it :)