# How to find UI menu files in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

in order to solve a dev. menu code problem, as the post title tell, I am struggling to find UI menu files in Wordpress. As you can see, (and please have a look at this [link](http://goo.gl/xGBMtI)) there is a code implemented into the `header.php` file that should offer some pointers on where the current menu UI is held (unfortunately not exactly yet), outputting “menu1” and “menu2”;

At this point, I'm not so sure where are these located, in order to analyse/modify the UI menu files.

I know that generally these are held under `wp-content` folder, but where more exactly? because I can't find them.

In `function.php` I've found this

```
...
// Add Menu Support 
require_once('inc/wp3menu.php'); 
...
```

nothing more about menu1 or menu2 sections ...Also in `wp3menu.php` the same story (true there is `Walker_Nav_Menu` but no menu1 / 2 sections).

I know that names and links are stored in the database, but the UI files will be housed in files somewhere in the code base; is this available in every WP theme?

I appreciate it,
Thanks.

Comment: hi, thank you for your feedback. Doesn't help too much because actually, it's more than that. I am interested in backend code, not in the wp menu section.This is an additional question to this one if you have a few moments to see the [whole picture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861567/how-to-properly-implement-a-structured-menu-in-php).

Comment: wordpress offers the codex which has links to relevant functions, starting point for you is `wp_nav_menu` which will unearth the db data eventually and the default walker class which deals with the rendering.  e.g. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker (see source file reference). Themes can select their own walker if needed, but usually only for mega menu types or something different.  Have fun!

Comment: thanks, I'll have a good look;